# Multilevel Inheritance in Entity Framework by TPT strategy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Suppose this is the case, I want a separate table for every class (including abstract).

[image: DB Schema Snapshot]

Here is the DBContext:

```
public class AIOmedicareContext : DbContext
{

    public AIOmedicareContext() : base("name=AIOmedicareConnectionString")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
            .ToTable("Roles")
            .HasKey(p => p.PrimaryKey)
            .Property(p => p.PrimaryKey)
            .HasColumnName("RoleID")
            .HasColumnOrder(1);

        // Moved all Person related configurations to PersonConfiguration class.
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfiguration());

        // Moved all User related configurations to UserConfiguration class.
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());

        // Moved all Employee related configurations to EmployeeConfiguration class.
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmployeeConfiguration());



        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

Entity Confugrations

**PersonConfiguration.cs**

```
public class PersonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public PersonConfiguration()
    {
        // Database table name
        this.ToTable("Person")
            .HasKey<Guid>(p => p.PrimaryKey);

        // every person have atmost one account.
        this.HasOptional<Account>(s => s.Account);

        // PrimaryKey property mapped to PersonID column in database.
        this.Property(p => p.PrimaryKey)
            .HasColumnName("PersonID")
            .HasColumnOrder(1);

        // a person can have many contacts.
        this.HasMany<Contact>(c => c.Contacts)
            .WithRequired(p => p.Person)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.PersonID);

        // a person can have many addresses.
        this.HasMany<Address>(p => p.Addresses)
            .WithRequired(a => a.Person)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.PersonID);
    }
}
```

**EmployeeConfiguration.cs**

```
class EmployeeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Employees")
            .HasKey(p => p.PrimaryKey)
            .Property(e => e.PrimaryKey)
            .HasColumnName("EmployeeID")
            .HasColumnOrder(1);

        this.HasMany<Role>(u => u.Roles)
            .WithMany(e => e.Employees)
            .Map(re => {
                re.MapLeftKey("EmployeeRefID");
                re.MapRightKey("RoleRefID");
                re.ToTable("EmployeeRole");
            });
    }
}
```

**UserConfiguration.cs**

```
class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Users")
            .HasKey(p => p.PrimaryKey)
            .Property(u => u.PrimaryKey)
            .HasColumnName("UserID")
            .HasColumnOrder(1);

        this.HasMany(u => u.UserLogs)
            .WithRequired(ul => ul.User)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserID);

        this.HasMany(u => u.Permissions)
            .WithOptional(p => p.User)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserID);
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a object of **User** through a console application but it throwing the following exceptions.

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.FirstName = "Sandeep";
        user.LastName = "Sihari";
        user.Age = 15;
        user.Sex = "Male";
        user.JoiningDate = DateTime.Now;
        user.UserName = "qwerty";
        user.HashedPassword = CalculateHash("qwerty", user.UserName);

        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.Type = new ContactType() { Name = "Office" };
        contact.Name = "Sandeep";
        contact.Number = "123456";
        contact.Description = "No description";
        user.AddContact(contact);

        ISessionFactory factory = new SessionFactory();
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = factory.CurrentUoW;
        IRepository repository = new Repository(unitOfWork);
        unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();

        repository.AddEntity(user);

        unitOfWork.CommitTransaction();

        Console.WriteLine("Operation completed.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string CalculateHash(string clearTextPassword, string salt)
    {
        // Convert the salted password to a byte array
        byte[] saltedHashBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearTextPassword + salt);
        // Use the hash algorithm to calculate the hash
        HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(saltedHashBytes);
        // Return the hash as a base64 encoded string to be compared to the stored password
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
}
```

Here is the error.

> Error retrieving values from ObjectStateEntry. See inner exception for details.

And inner exception is:

> (23,10) : error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 23, 34:EntityTypes AIOmedicare.DAL.EF.Employee, AIOmedicare.DAL.EF.Customer, AIOmedicare.DAL.EF.User are being mapped to the same rows in table Person. Mapping conditions can be used to distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.

Migrations are applied successfully, and have verified the tables are present through SQL Server Management Studio.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Could you show a more simplified reproduction of the issue?  For example, code that isn't being called because you are getting the error first could be removed as it is extraneous to the problem you are having.

Comment: can you be more specific. i am not completely understand what you are saying?

Comment: You have posted quite a bit of code. Can you remove the parts that aren't relevant to the problem?

Comment: almost everything is relevant to the problem. i know its a lot of code but i have tried everything before posting it here. thats why i wanted to give the detail info of problem.